# SWIG Wrap Existing DLL

Tags: c#, windows, dll, pinvoke, swig

I have an existing dll (written in C build with MinGW) and knowledge of its contents (function names, parameters, return types, etc.). I want to use SWIG to call the dll through C#. As a trial I tried the below steps with the tutorial example in http://swig.org/tutorial.html

I turned the example.c into a dll like so:

```
gcc -shared -m32 example.c -o mainDLL.dll
```

This created mainDLL.dll. I then ran SWIG on example.i:

```
swig.exe -csharp example.i
```

This creates the C# files and an example_wrap.c file. The PINVOKE expects to call all the SWIG functions on a dll called example.dll. So I create it using the SWIG wrapper and mainDLL.dll:

```
gcc -shared -m32 example_wrap.c mainDLL.dll -o example.dll
Info: resolving _My_variable by linking to __imp__My_variable (auto-import)
```

I then took the two dlls and placed them in my executable's folder (bin\x86\Debug). Then I try to call the content of the dll through C# I get an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException:
    The type initializer for 'examplePINVOKE' threw an exception. ---> 
System.TypeInitializationException:
    The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception. ---> 
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 
    Unable to find an entry point named 'SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_example' in DLL 'example'.
```

I used dependency walker to make sure that SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_example exists in example.dll. Does anyone know how to use SWIG with an existing DLL?

Comment: For all my SWIG/C# on Windows needs I've always built the DLLs using MSVC as well as the C#. I mean it should be possible to make it work with gcc, but normally that takes extra faff on Windows in my experience.

Comment: I have never used SWIG for C#, but on many occasions, I have used SWIG for Python using gcc. Try compile it with the `-fPIC` option.